# Making for loop a promise and waiting for it

Tags: node.js

I have a for loop which executes functions asynchronously, when everything in the for loop is done I want to invoke my callback. Currently the callback is getting executed at the same time as the for loop begings.

```js
const loop = (callback) => {
  for(const domain of domains) {
    throttle(() => {
      fetchData(domain)
        .then((data) => {
          if (data[0]) {
            if (
              typeof (
                data[1] === undefined ||
                typeof (data[1].settings[1].protocol === undefined)
              )
            ) {
            }
            data = data[1];
            if (
              data.settings[1].protocol != "IMAP" ||
              providerExist(data.domain)
            )
              return;

            addProvider(
              data.domain,
              data.settings[1].address,
              data.settings[1].port
            );
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(`${err}`);
        });
    });
  }
  callback(); // this gets run at the same time as the for loop begins
}
```

I know I should be using a promise but I'm not quite sure how to implement it here as I'm still new to using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see:

```
// returns a promise 
const handleDomainAsync = (domain) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        throttle(() => {
            fetchData(domain)
                .then((data) => {
                    if (!data[0])
                        return;

                    if (typeof (data[1] === undefined || typeof (data[1].settings[1].protocol === undefined))) {

                        // this 
                    }
                    data = data[1];
                    if (
                        data.settings[1].protocol != "IMAP" ||
                        providerExist(data.domain)
                    )
                        return;

                    addProvider(
                        data.domain,
                        data.settings[1].address,
                        data.settings[1].port
                    );

                    resolve();
                })
                .catch((err) => {

                    console.log(`${err}`);
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    });
}

const loop = (callback) => {

    // this holds all promises that will finish sometime in the future 
    const handlerPromises = [];

    // this aggregates all handler promises to the declared array
    for (const domain of domains) {

        handlerPromises.push(handleDomainAsync(domain));
    }

    // this will "await" all promises and only continue (in the then, or error) 
    // when the promises completed, or errored   
    Promise
        .all(handlerPromises)
        .then(() => {

            callback(); // this gets run at the same time as the for loop begins
        })
        .catch(() => { })
}
```

What you are looking for is probably the Promise.All() funciton.
Also, if you handle promises, when waiting one and then doung something occures, you can always wrap the whole thing in another promise, that's .then() will be called after the first promise has finished running.

Bottom line, a good advice: if you can, use TypeScript, and async/await, it's a whole other world which is much cleaner, easier to use and learn. And it's not too hard to configure it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).